# c#: How to iterate through a List<>, that is a value in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Right now I have a dictionary being populated with an account as key, and a List as value.  I believe my code is working to populate it.  But my next step is to iterate through that List associated with a particularly key and do stuff with the list (get sums for each field).  I am not that familiar with dictionaries so I am not sure how to access the values and perform an action.  I would like to do this summation and print it out in my for each loop, when I exit the while loop.

1) If I could figure out how to access each field in DataRecords (inside the foreach loop), I could likely figure out how to do the summation.

2) Also looking for a way to print the values so I can see if it is even populated correctly.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<DataRecord>> vSummaryResults = new Dictionary<string, List<DataRecord>>();

    while (!r.EndOfStream)
    {
        if (control == "1")
        {
            // Need to add List<Datarecords> into dictionary...
            if (vSummaryResults.ContainsKey(records.account))
            {
                vSummaryResults[records.account].Add(records);
            }
            else
            {
                vSummaryResults.Add(records.account, new List<DataRecord>());
                vSummaryResults[records.account].Add(records);
            }
        }
   }
   foreach (List<DataRecord> rec in vSummaryResults.Values)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(rec.);  dictionary.
   }
   vWriteFile.Close();
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Here is my `DataRecord` class that I am using as the object in the List.

public class DataRecord
{
    fields.....
}

Comment: You've given us a lot of code there, with a complex `DataRecord` type. Could you please try to simplify this to a [mcve]? That will make it easier to help you, and it will make the post more helpful to others in the future too.

Comment: Sorry about that, did my edits help?

Comment: You need another loop to access each element of the `List<DataRecord>`: `foreach (DataRecord dataRecord in rec) { Console.WriteLine(dataRecord.?);  }`

Comment: No, it's now badly formatted and incomplete, but no clearer. Please follow the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For iterations over a dictionary, we use [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<DataRecord>> kvp in vSummaryResults)
{
  string key = kvp.Key;
  List<DataRecord> list = kvp.Value;

  Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, contains {1} values:", key, list.Count);
  foreach (DataRecord rec in list)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("  - Value = {0}", rec.ToString()); // or whatever you do to put list value on the output
  }
}
```

Comment: You might add a note that he's missing an iteration of the actual list via `foreach`, but I think the answer is still complete without it

Comment: This is perfect, I could do my summation from knowing how to do this, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I made an example with a simple situation. Its a list of strings, but you can do the object.ToString() to get some tekst;

To loop over the list contained by the key you need to iterate over that list again that is what the 2nd foreach does.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

List<String> ls = new List<string>();

ls.Add("item1");
ls.Add("item2");

dictionary.Add("it1", ls);
dictionary.Add("it2", ls);

foreach (var item in dictionary)
{
    foreach(var it in item.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(it);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a dictionary

`Dictionary<string, List<DataRecord>> vSummaryResults = new Dictionary<string, List<DataRecord>>();`

You could do a

```
foreach (List<DataRecord> recs in vSummaryResults.Values)
{
    foreach (DataRecord rec in recs)
       Console.WriteLine(rec.Something); 
}
```

You haven't specified what DataRecord looks like, but you would get a list of list. There's probably a lovely Linq expression that could do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need another loop inside the first to get values in your list.

```
foreach (List<DataRecord> rec in vSummaryResults.Values)
{
    foreach(DataRecord data in rec)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data .YourProperty);
    }
}
```

If you know the key:

```
foreach (List<DataRecord> rec in vSummaryResults[key])
{
    foreach(DataRecord data in rec)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(data .YourProperty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand it from reading your code, you have a dictionary where each key has a list of type DataRecord.

With your current loop

```
foreach (List<DataRecord> rec in vSummaryResults.Values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rec.);  dictionary.

    }
```

You looped through each List of type DataRecord. To access the data stored in each object in each list you will need to include another foreach loop to loop through the objects in the list.

```
 foreach (var rec in vSummaryResults.Values)
    {
        // At this point we have access to each individual List<DataRecord>
    foreach(var SingleDataRecordObj in rec)

     Console.WriteLine(ingleDataRecordObj.membervariablename)
      //From here we are able to list the individual variable member names      of values that are in the DataRecord data type, showing all of the information in each list that is stored in the values of the dictionary

    }
```

You can't modify the data in the foreach loop, but you could add them a more simple data structure to perform whatever commutation you wanted etc.

Comment: Right now I am trying to sum the fields in DataRecord.  It is working, just not the way I want, as it is summing all the "fields" for all the accounts, as opposed to summing the fields, per account.

Comment: if (vSummaryResults.ContainsKey(key))
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("Value = {0}", rec.open);
                        iSumOpen += rec.open;

                        //Console.WriteLine("Value = {0}", rec.ToString());
                        // or whatever you do to put list value on the output
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vSummaryResults.Add(key, list);
                    }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for exactly what I needed to do.  Working the way I need it to now, thanks for everyone's help.

```
    int iSumOpen = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<DataRecord>> kvp in vSummaryResults)
        {
            string key = kvp.Key; //assigns key
            List<DataRecord> list = kvp.Value;  //assigns value

            Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}", key);
            iSumOpen = 0;
            foreach (DataRecord rec in list)
            {
                if (vSummaryResults.ContainsKey(key))
                {

                    iSumOpen += rec.open;

                }

                else
                {
                    vSummaryResults.Add(key, list);
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(iSumOpen);
        }
```